# $f$ converges then $f'$ converges to $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and differentiable. Assume that 
$$
 \lim_{x  \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = y_0 \in \mathbb R
$$

Is it then true that 
$$
 \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0 
$$ ?

Comment: May the 4 downvoters who downvoted this question step forward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}\sin(x^2)$ which converges to zero as $x \to \infty$ but $f^{'}(x) = \frac{-1}{x^2} \sin(x^2) + 2\cos(x^2)$ does not converge as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: Yeah thanks. It was just and intuitive idea, so thanks for this example.

Comment: Why does the question have so many down votes??

Comment: I was confused, too. Next time I will think more deeply about my questions, first.